# Fill object with Random Box packing in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a node setup in Geometry nodes that will allow me to fill/pack a base object like 'Suzanne' with boxes like the examples below:

[image]

I've managed to somewhat get the effect via distributing points within a mesh volume but it ends up looking more like a minecraft model than the more randomised, hand-stacked look I'm hoping to achieve...

I've seen some examples in other software where this effect is achieved using packing algorithms and physics simulations so I'm wondering if there's something similar I could do in Blender or maybe workaround methods for shuffling up the grid?

[image]

Would also be great to be able to control things like random rotation for the boxes and the gap size/density between them if possible

[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: collision detection of rotated boxes is tricky, so a very significant piece of information is how correct you want the arrangement to be, how much do you want to avoid overlap, and how densely do you want to pack. Clearly, the most dense packing is just a 3D grid of touching cubes. If you provide cuboids and want to pack them, then it becomes a mathematical challenge. If you want dense packing of non-cube cuboids, you could start with a 3D grid and merge cubes together - but that still doesn't have rotation.

Comment: Thanks Markus the idea would be to avoid as much overlap as possible - would it be easier if say the packing had to select from a predefined series of box sizes?
I.e. a box that is wider, a box that is a perfect cube, a box that is skinny etc. and then fit these together as best as possible...

Or what about if I setup some kind of modular grid that the cuboids would be able to fit within i.e. 0.1m base grid that could then have varying cuboid sizes of that increment somehow?
I'm really stumped and would love to know some kind of method for achieving this.

Comment: As you mentioned in your question it's all about algorithms and they are computationally intensive. Similarly to the Shortest Edge Paths Node which is an implementation of the Dijkstra’s algorithm it will be quite challenging to recreate them with the available nodes. Hopefully in the future we'll get more art oriented algorithms implemented.  Using Simulation could be an interesting approach (like some sort of Tetris), but may leave some of the boxes unnaturally hanging , or spawning a box on available surface, shooting 5 rays to find the closest face and then scaling up the box apropriately.

Comment: I did some tests yesterday and it seems just using Raycast node won't help. It is more like a Geo Proximity Node type of problem. I posted a small description about the steps here: https://curiousblends.blogspot.com/2023/12/a-box-packing-algorithm-with-geometry.html?view=sidebar , but it needs some polishing.

Comment: perhaps try adding some random rotation